# Clank! Legacy Necrosis Rules

Tags: clank

! Clank! Legacy Spoilers Ahead !

With Necrosis you need to Heal to get rid of the card.

If you have no damage can you Heal the  Necrosis with a forest space? Can you trash Necrosis at a volcano?

Comment: Having only played the base and *in Space*, my first thought based solely on your post is that you shouldn't be penalized for not having been damaged. If something would heal you if you had damage, it should heal the Necrosis even if you have no damage. Again, I haven't read the rules or anything of the kind.

Answer (score 1):

My group's understanding of the rules was you need damage in order to heal. The text on the card states "If you ❤️ this turn" meaning it is the result of an action. If there was no damage then there was no ❤️ action taken.

Comment: Are there any official rulings to back up your opinion? Necrosis seems like an aliment that would need a cure, such as forcing to stop at a healing location or spend a healing token to get rid of it.

Comment: In the "Step 4: The Getaway" section of the base game it specifically states that healing happens damage is taken.  This and the rest of the text can all not be accomplished if there is no damage cube. Obviously, if you want to make a house rule to make the necrosis less punishing that is totally up to your party! Games are for fun.

Comment: correction, the exact words are "Some effects can heal damage you've taken".